# Run a project / script from another project with nao robot / Choregraphe

Tags: nao-robot

For my Nao robot active process i want to load and run another project ones condition is true. Is it possible? 
If so how do i do it in Choregraphe?

Exp: IF face recognition recognize person a THEN load and play file project b

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in Choregraphe, you can do this with the boxes under Programming / Behavior Control in the box library: "Run Behavior" or "Start Behavior".

You can also directly control behaviors from a custom python box with [ALBehaviorManager](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-8/naoqi/core/albehaviormanager.html)